# Why is deleting data discouraged in Grails?

Tags: grails, persistence, grails-orm

From http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.3.2%20Deleting%20Objects:

> Note that Grails does not supply a deleteAll method as deleting data is discouraged and can often be avoided through boolean flags/logic.

Why is deleting data discouraged?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they're actually saying that deleting data is bad, but they don't provide a convenience method for deleting all data in a table, because it's possible that you might accidentally call

```
book.deleteAll()
```

when you meant to type

```
book.delete()
```

and the consequences of that could be fairly dire. If you really want to delete all instances, it's as simple as:

```
Book.executeUpdate("delete Book")
```

which is something you're unlikely to invoke accidentally

Answer (score 2):

Like Don, I agree that they're not saying it's completely bad.

The way I read that documentation quote is that, in many applications, it's more appropriate to flag a record as "hidden" or "expired" instead of deleting it, and then remove it from displays/queries/etc. accordingly. This is mostly for applications that require historical data preservation or auditing.

The advice is definitely situational, and depends on the requirements of your application.